# neo4j starts then immediately stops

Tags: neo4j

```
root@921206babbc9:/# /var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j console

Starting Neo4j Server console-mode...

Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:hashCode=5 -Dneo4j.ext.udc.source=debian

2015-06-01 16:39:34.082+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on 120000

2015-06-01 16:39:35.100+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server.
```

Running neo4j v2.2.2 in a Docker container. On one environment, the thing starts up just fine, but on another, with more data, it does this start then stop trick. Note that neither environment has much data at all. Barely double digits number of nodes.

The databases were upgraded from an older version of neo4j recently.

Anyway, with that log output I'm not really sure where to go with this. Does anyone have a clue as to what might cause it to launch and just shutdown on its own? (Notice that the time delta between the last two entries in that log is just a second or so.)

---

EDIT: Looks like the DB didn't cleanly shut down. Found this in `messages.log`:

```
2015-06-01 16:39:35.102+0000 ERROR [o.n.s.CommunityBootstrapper]: Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j Server failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@6d7232a5' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:255) ~[neo4j-server-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:117) [neo4j-server-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:69) [neo4j-server-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@6d7232a5' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:203) ~[neo4j-server-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /data/neo4j
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:334) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase$1.newGraphDatabase(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:44) ~[neo4j-server-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:110) ~[neo4j-server-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager@7aff1fa3' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:330) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@5db7419c' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:117) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UpgradingStoreVersionNotFoundException: 'neostore.nodestore.db' does not contain a store version, please ensure that the original database was shut down in a clean state.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradableDatabase.checkUpgradeable(UpgradableDatabase.java:86) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreMigrator.needsMigration(StoreMigrator.java:158) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.getParticipantsEagerToMigrate(StoreUpgrader.java:259) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.migrateIfNeeded(StoreUpgrader.java:134) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.upgradeStore(NeoStoreDataSource.java:560) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:461) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Is there any additional info in `data/log/neo4j.0.0.log`? Also, you mention the database was recently upgraded. From some versions of Neo4j there is [an explicit store upgrade flag that needs to be set](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.0/deployment-upgrading.html).

Comment: Yep, we set the upgrade flag.

Comment: We will try and run the old version of the container and make sure it shuts down cleanly. Then I need to get `messages.log` to just go to `stdout`... See: http://serverfault.com/questions/664021/neo4j-docker-coreos-logging-everything-to-the-console

Comment: What version did you upgrade from? And did you incrementally upgrade from one version to the next?

Comment: Upgraded from 2.1.7. My other environments upgraded without issue though.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem *was* that it had not shut down cleanly before upgrading. Using the previous version's container and ensuring a clean shutdown solved the problem.